# sort on month and year

Tags: 2013, list, date-time

In my custom list i have columns month and year. Both are string column.
This is my query to get data

```
 Query = @"   <Where><And><Eq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Boolean'>1</Value></Eq>
                                         <And><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='month' /></IsNotNull>
                                         <IsNotNull><FieldRef Name='
                                 Year' /></IsNotNull>
                                         </And>
                                         </And>
                                     </Where>
                                     <OrderBy>

                                       <FieldRef Name='Year' Ascending='False' />
                                     </OrderBy>"
```

If i store data in list as

Month----------------Year

March----------------2016

April----------------2016

October----------------2016

Then the above query gives me below output

Month----------------Year

October----------------2016

March----------------2016

April----------------2016

It should be April before and then march. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't really going to be able to in that fashion with a string sort. You will need to make them 10 - October, 03 - March, 04 - April for them to sort correctly or introduce an ordering column as an alternate way to sort the values.

```
Month----------------Year

03 - March----------------2016

04 - April----------------2016

10 - October----------------2016
```

You are also missing a sort in your CAML, you'd want it to be:

```
<OrderBy>
   <FieldRef Name='Year' Ascending='False' />
   <FieldRef Name='Month' Ascending='True' />
</OrderBy>
```

Comment: how can i make them as 10-october 03 runtime?

Comment: by the way i just use month and year

Comment: my both columns are strings. So you mean i create calculated column based on these two columns? But still how can i do it with calcualted column?

Comment: No, I mean physically change the month values to 03 - March or create a new sort order column that you give correct sort order for.

Comment: Sorry bit unsure still. You mean user will select 03-March from dropdown?

Comment: i created seperate column (MonthName)which stores month from 01-12. Then i sort by monthname and year descending and its giving correct result. So should i create calculated column if user selects March then column MonthName is set to 3 automatically.. will it be ok?

Comment: i even tried your solution but that too doesnt sort correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to create a column in list, then create a calculated column with formula as

```
=IF([Month]="March", 03,IF([Month]="April",04))
```

this will generate the number for the corresponding order, later on, you can use this column to sort.

If you want to make it work on a form for a field to display the options in sort, below should work.
Create a HTML control in ur form as below

```
<select id="ControlID" name="Month">
  <option value="03">March</option>
  <option value="04">April</option>
  <option value="05">May</option>
  <option value="10">October</option>
</select>
```

You can keep the sequence of options as you want in above control,

And keep your actual control hidden from form.
Use Jquery/Javascript. 
On change event of the new control, pick its value and set in your original control.

Comment: how can i use this code to create list column

Comment: You create a Single line of text column. suppose 'X' using your code which should not be a problem. Just to handle the problem of displaying it in sequence/order on form, I have provided solution.

Comment: Looks like you have not understood question or i am not able to explain

Comment: If you are using custom form and the requirement is just to display Month/Years in order, and required to store it in any pattern then, my solution should be enough to fulfill your need

Comment: Hope you are talking about sharepoint list? See user goes in list and he select month and year. I wish to sort those columns.

Comment: oops. Now got ur point, you need to sort the list data, and not the values of a control for a specific item. Earlier I thought  you have 2 columns, you need to display their data in order, on a Edit/Create form/page, Sorry my solution is not relevent to your requirement. Let me think and provide you some solution

Comment: Now you well understood.

Comment: Please find the updated solution

Comment: i cant even create calcuated column based on month name because month names will be different based on country

Comment: Conutry is new in scenario here. :D by Country, u mean in month will be provided in different languages. If so any idea, how many unique months are already added based on contries? Also is Month a choice column or Single line of text?

Comment: Month is choice column. Currently its just added for 1 country

Answer (score 0):

All credits to Christophe

http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2013/10/31/trick-or-treat-group-items-by-month/

Basic concept is to use a Calculated Column **and pad the string with spaces** (which your browser ignores)

```
 =REPT( " " , 13-MONTH(Modified) )  &  TEXT( Modified , "mmmm" )
```